# Looking for Online Data Storage Software/Web Application

Tags: web-apps, database, microsoft-excel, crm, spreadsheet

The company that I work for has collected a LOT of data (hundreds of thousands of entries) in Excel spreadsheets that are separated into labelled columns (ex. Name, Number, E-mail, Address, etc.).

We need somewhere online to import all of the data while still displaying them in spreadsheet form. Also, we have a team of agents working for us who need to access and view the data, make changes (we would like to edit their privileges under an admin account), add new contacts, and claim certain contacts as potential prospects so that others may not edit it.

A mobile app counterpart is also a requirement. The ability to create our own fields is very important. The more customization we can have, the better. We have tried several CRMs already, but they either cannot handle our data, do not have key features that we need, or have terrible support systems.

We've begun to think that maybe we shouldn't be looking for CRMs but databases instead.

Comment: Goodness yes, you need to dump it all to database tables, NOT more excel

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Wolfram Alpha [Data Drop](https://datadrop.wolframcloud.com/) service.

You could configure this to receive your data in a number of formats including emailing or tweeting into the database, imports from various source.
Similarly, you can read from it in a number of formats and create your own reports or analyses.

There is a Wolfram Alpha [mobile app](http://products.wolframalpha.com/mobile/) but, at present, it doesn't directly support Data Drop.  This feature is described as "*Coming soon*".

Answer (score 1):

I believe there a couple fo ways you can tackle you question, however it is important to keep in mind as to "what do you want to do with this data?". Basically if it is just for storage and edit, or maybe you would like to make some analysis? Below are a couple of possible solutions, since you were not precise on your use (how you wish to structure your data, ect), I am making broad approaches (links at the bottom):

**1 - Use Cloud Provider + Document Editor:** this is basically using Google Drive/OneDrive/Dropbox as your cloud repository and edit the files with both online and also client installations spreadsheets editor of your choice. You can go strictly Google Docs style, or maintain your Excel formats and use web excel (there are mobile apps for all of these platforms). I would not really recommend this, especially if you have a lot of data, but it is definitely an option.

**2 - Use Document Management Software:** like LogicalDOC, OpenKM, Alfresco, etc. There are OpenSource options for these. Now, they are not spreadsheet exclusive, they manage all types of documents and files. This is excellent for handling not just a very large quantity of files, but also a variety of file types. Some have editing capabilities, but for full feature you would have to go with the commercial options.

**3 - Use Database:** this would be my best choice. You have a variety of DataBase editors - MS Access, Libre Office Base, FileMaker Pro, among others - where you can have multiple types of databases, as well as custom fields, etc. Mobile access, use cloud service for access management, among other possible scenarios. Very flexible and customisable.

All of the above are basically for keeping the data in place, editing, updating and also sharing (managing access). Now, for data handling and also *analysing*, I would suggest:

**4 - Use data analysis platform:** Microsoft Power BI. This is a fantastic tool for data management and analysis. It can connect to excel, Access, among other database formats and online storage providers. Provides tools for analysis and reporting. Although you cannot edit via mobile, you can view reports and data sets. Other tools for analysis like Tableau are also great, however they do not have a Free version (only trial) for you to be able to get a hang of the platform.

If I have not helped you with a direct solution, I hope I at least assisted in guiding you to the right direction.

Below the links:

https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/

https://www.tableau.com/

http://www.filemaker.com/

https://www.logicaldoc.com/

https://www.openkm.com/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you are still looking for a solution but if you do, check out [Simitless](https://www.simitless.com/). It is an online platform that enables you to build your own information system/data management app (call it a database if you want). And you can determine yourself what fields (i.e. spreadsheet columns) you want to include to track your data. In other words, it is fully customizable to the needs you have. It is an online platform, so also accessible on your mobile via a mobile browser. I think it actually checks the majority of your boxes:

- it is in the cloud (no need to install anything),
- accessible on mobile,
- customizable to your particular needs,
- you can determine yourself who can access the data, how they can access them (just view, view and edit, etc.),
- you can import and export data. 
  Maybe it is something that you would be interested in trying out.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand. Just get in touch. (If you want to quickly try it out, there is an [Online Contacts Directory App](https://simitless.com/en/templates?or=st&preview=templates-online-contacts-directory) template that I have made according to what you have described that you would like to track. Click the eye icon to preview the template with "dummy data". And, since it is just a template, you can take it as a basis and modify it to your heart's desire.) It might be just what you are looking for. And let me know how it goes, if you decide to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

[Smartsheet](https://www.smartsheet.com/) is also a popular choice for your set of requirements. Check it out

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into [airtable](https://airtable.com/). I  personally tried the mobile counterpart app and it works well too.

For 100,000 entries your going to want to contact them on pricing. Pricing is fairly reasonable, last I checked I'm paying $24/user/month

The best part of it is with higher tiered you can control what users see which data to work with